# storefront_sticky_add_to_cart refuses to be removed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Almost finished my WooCommerce Storefront child theme.

There's a block sitting under the footer on the product pages that I have zero desire to keep. Just as I've done with a few other extraneous pieces of markup, I tracked down the action and removed it:

```
remove_action( 'storefront_after_footer', 'storefront_sticky_single_add_to_cart');
```

... It is still showing in the page.

I've even tried some random things I found:

```
add_filter ('storefront_sticky_add_to_cart', '__return_false');
```

and

```
function cleanup_parent_filters()
{
    //...
    remove_action( 'storefront_after_footer', 'storefront_sticky_single_add_to_cart');
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'cleanup_parent_filters');
```

With no results.

This is really more annoying than anything. I can remove the entire `do_action( 'storefront_after_footer' );` from the template as I really just don't care to have it there, but now I need to know why this is not working as expected out of principle.

Comment: **For info:** In the customizer > Product page, there is an option to enable / disable the "Sticky Add-To-Cart'…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
remove_action( 'storefront_after_footer',
               'storefront_sticky_single_add_to_cart', 999 );
```

`remove_action` needs the priority value as it was used to add the action. From the [Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

> **Important**: To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority
>   arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both
>   filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.

And why 999? [From the source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/search?q=storefront_sticky_single_add_to_cart&unscoped_q=storefront_sticky_single_add_to_cart).

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this out.